# Magento 1 to 2 data migration root'@'localhost Access denied situation

Tags: magento2, migration, magento2-migration-tool

Getting there with a Magento 1 to 2 data migration but when I get here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-migrate-settings.html  and run  php bin/magento:settings  I get and permissions issue. How do I open up these permissions in MySql? I have the user root set up to have schema privileges to the DB.

[Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using pas
  sword: NO)

[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using pas
  sword: NO)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have getting *this issue for wrongly configure at config.xml which is located at*

```
[your Magento 2 install dir]/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/[migration edition]/[ce or version]
```

***Here ,you have put wrong setting between Magento2 and Magento 1***

> ```
> <source>
>     <database host="[HostLocation]" name="[magento1DB]" user="[DBUSER]" password="[Db_PASSWORD_FOR_magento1DB_USER]"/>
> </source>
> <destination>
>     <database host="[HostLocation]" name="[magento2DB]" user="[DBUSER]" password="[Db_PASSWORD_FOR_magento2DB_USER]"/>
> </destination>
> <options>
>     <crypt_key />
> </options>
> ```

Please check this. Hope it will resolve the issue.

See configuraion setting of migration tool http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-configure.html